# What is the intuitive explanation of Attention Maps?

Tags: neural-networks

I just came across this link. https://medium.com/moonvision/want-better-accuracy-for-classification-models-lets-use-attention-maps-6d687c8e7625

But I did not understand what exactly are those and how is it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and read through the attention paper, to have a better understanding of how the attention mechanism works in simple cases, you can read the following [article](https://distill.pub/2016/augmented-rnns/) on the subject, then you can try and understand how the same mechanism can be used to improve predictions on image data using attention maps.